# How can I count discrete items?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given the table:

```
verdict    region   name 
good         US     pat  
good         US     sally 
bad        France   john
```

how can I count the number of people in `US` and verdict is `good`?

I have tried using SUMPRODUCT and COUNT but no luck as SUMPRODUCT seems to require numeric values and COUNT only acts on one column. For example:

```
=COUNT(C5:C7="US")
=SUMPRODUCT(--(J2:J7="US"),K2:K7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"good",B:B,"us")
```

Note: this assumes that Verdicts are in column A and Regions are in column B. Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

ColumnC and ColumnJ in your examples is confusing but if `verdict` is in A1 then two more possibilities are (1) fixing your SUMPRODUCT formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7="US")*(A2:A7="good"))
```

and (2) the more versatile and comprehensive PivotTable option:

[image: SO3348726 example]

In [SUMPRODUCT](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) `A2:A7="good"` looks at each of the six cells and returns an array of TRUE or FALSE entries according to whether the comparison is 'correct' (say A3 *is* `good`) or incorrect. The "PRODUCT part" of the function then takes each of the elements of the B2:B7 array and multiplies in turn by the corresponding element of the A2:A7 array. When multiplying, `TRUE` is treated as `1` (`FALSE` as `0`). The resulting array (of `1`s or `0`s) is then added up by the "SUM part" of SUMPRODUCT.

To see this happening try Evaluate Formula.

Comment: Thx a mill. The 1st sln worked a treat, can you explain what sumproduct is doing, i can never get my head around it!

Comment: Seems unnecessarily compplicated yet seems to be the preferred method...instead of using COUNTIFS